# AddOpenIdConnect with local UserManager

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am using the OpenIdConnect middleware in my .net core application.

It is all working with my identity server, however, I want to track user activity in my site not just authenticate them.

To do so after the Token is validated, I have a custom event for `OnTokenValidated`

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0";
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.CallbackPath = "/Home/Login/";
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
            {
                var userId = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                {
                    //NEED HELP HERE
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

        options.Scope.Add("api1");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        options.ClaimActions.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims.JsonKeyClaimAction("role", null, "role"));

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });
```

I planned on using AspNetIdentity on my MVC application, which will check if the user who was just authenticated exists in my local database.

ISSUE:

How can I use the UserManager, from AspNetIdentity, within my `AddAuthentication`?

I guess I can create a DbContext and access it directly, but I would prefer to use the UserManage for consistency.

Comment: Hey, would you be able to share your full code on github or the like? I am trying to set up something similar with aspnet core identity and openid connect working together but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the database use UserManage like :

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
    {

        var _userManager = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        var users =await  _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

        ...
    },

};
```